# In UltraEdit how to see the corresponding '(' and ')'

Tags: sql, ultraedit

In Notepad++ and SQLDeveloper for writing SQL regarding '(' and ')' the corresponding ones are shown. Also a ')' too many will appear red.

Is it possibly to have this feature in UltraEdit (23.10.0.1) too and if so, how to accomplish that?

In the following link see a printscreen with an example in SQLDeveloper where in blue the corresponding one is shown and in red the one too many: http://prntscr.com/cq2l8n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UltraEdit the configuration setting *Enable auto-brace matching* must be enabled.

This setting can be found in configuration after opening **Advanced - Settings/Configuration** at

- **Editor - Braces / strings** with UE for Windows v23.20 / UES v16.20 and later versions;
- **Editor Display - Brace Matching** with UltraEdit v23.10 / UES v16.10 and former versions.

And additionally the active file must be syntax highlighted with a syntax language definition usually having the lines

```
/Open Brace Strings = "{" "(" "["
/Close Brace Strings = "}" ")" "]"
```

By default installed for syntax highlighting *.sql files is the wordfile `mysql.uew`. It contains the brace string definitions as shown above. Those open/close brace strings are also the internal defaults if a wordfile does not contain open and close brace string definitions.

The open/close brace strings defined in the wordfile are customizable by the user as the entire wordfile can be customized.

To customize an already used wordfile open **Advanced - Settings/Configuration - Editor Display - Syntax Highlighting**, select the language respectively installed wordfile to customize, click on button **Open** and close configuration dialog with button **Cancel**. Then make the changes in the opened wordfile and save it.

The changes are immediately active as it can be seen by switching from just edited wordfile to the file which is displayed according to edited syntax language. The status bar at bottom shows for active caret position in active file the currently active syntax highlighting language with the name defined in applied wordfile.

For example `html.uew` used by me for syntax highlighting HTML files contains:

```
/Open Brace Strings = "<a" "<acronym" "<b>" "<b" "<body" "<button" "<caption>" "<caption" "<dd>" "<dd" "<dir>" "<dir" "<div>" "<div" "<dl>" "<dl" "<dt>" "<dt" "<em>" "<em" "<font" "<form" "<frameset" "<h1>" "<h1" "<h2>" "<h2" "<h3>" "<h3" "<h4>" "<h4" "<h5>" "<h5" "<h6>" "<h6" "<head>" "<header>" "<i>" "<i" "<iframe" "<kbd>" "<kbd" "<li>" "<li" "<map" "<noframes>" "<noscript>" "<ol>" "<ol" "<option>" "<option" "<p>" "<p" "<pre>" "<pre" "<script>" "<script" "<select" "<small>" "<small" "<span" "<strong>" "<strong" "<style>" "<style" "<sub>" "<sub" "<sup>" "<sup" "<table>" "<table" "<td>" "<td" "<textarea" "<th>" "<th" "<title>" "<tr>" "<tr" "<tt>" "<tt" "<u>" "<u" "<ul>" "<ul" "<var>"
/Close Brace Strings = "</a>" "</acronym>" "</b>" "</b>" "</body>" "</button>" "</caption>" "</caption>" "</dd>" "</dd>" "</dir>" "</dir>" "</div>" "</div>" "</dl>" "</dl>" "</dt>" "</dt>" "</em>" "</em>" "</font>" "</form>" "</frameset>" "</h1>" "</h1>" "</h2>" "</h2>" "</h3>" "</h3>" "</h4>" "</h4>" "</h5>" "</h5>" "</h6>" "</h6>" "</head>" "</header>" "</i>" "</i>" "</iframe>" "</kbd>" "</kbd>" "</li>" "</li>" "</map>" "</noframes>" "</noscript>" "</ol>" "</ol>" "</option>" "</option>" "</p>" "</p>" "</pre>" "</pre>" "</script>" "</script>" "</select>" "</small>" "</small>" "</span>" "</strong>" "</strong>" "</style>" "</style>" "</sub>" "</sub>" "</sup>" "</sup>" "</table>" "</table>" "</td>" "</td>" "</textarea>" "</th>" "</th>" "</title>" "</tr>" "</tr>" "</tt>" "</tt>" "</u>" "</u>" "</ul>" "</ul>" "</var>"
```

Because UltraEdit as a very powerful general text editor not designed for a specific language has no syntax **checking** feature for SQL or any other language, a parenthesis being placed somewhere wrong is not special highlighted like SQLDeveloper does.

The text foreground and background color for the highlighted braces respectively `Brace Strings` can be customized since UltraEdit for Windows v20.00 and UEStudio v14.00 in the **Manage Themes** dialog on tab **Editor** which contains the item *Brace Highlight*.

Brace highlighting is disabled for active file even if enabled in configuration if no syntax highlighting is active on active file.